# Set git commit hash as dll version number in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, versioning

I'm developing a project using visual studio 2013 and git.

I must distribute some libraries of the project so I'd like to set their version number with the current git commit hash, so I can be sure of which library version they are using.

Is there a way to put the hash as version number in automated way, I.e. with a pre-build event, instead of doing it manually every time?

Comment: we have a bunch of msbuild code for that but I'm not allowed to distribute the whole of it. Not sure if you'd be helped with pieces of it, but the principle is: use a resource file template with a VERSIONINFO structure dfined. In a prebuild event, populate the template with the output of `git rev-parse --short HEAD` (along with company name and whatnot) and call rc.exe to create a .res file. All this code is stored in a property sheet, which also adds the .res file to the project's resources. As such all you have to do for a new project is import 1 single file and everything just works

Comment: it seems a good solution I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: Alexey's answer should get you started, for C#, if you want I can post an answer with some snippets for C++

Comment: Yes please it will be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some snippets of a possible implementation for native projects using resource files. The idea is to add a single property sheet to the project, which has a prebuild event which creates a .res file based on the git commit hash and which also adds this .res file as a resource. Here is the property sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionResourceOut>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\version.res</VersionResourceOut>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="$(VersionResourceOut)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(BuildToolsDir)tools\versionrc.targets" />
  <Target Name="CreateGitVersionResource" BeforeTargets="BuildGenerateSources">
    <CallTarget Targets="CreateGitVersionResInBuild" />
    <MakeSameWriteTime SourceFile="$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)" DestFile="$(VersionResourceOut)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The $(BuildToolsDir)tools\versionrc.targets file is where the actual creation of the resource file is done. The complete implementation is rather lengthy because it also works for svn and allows a bunch of customisation - a bit much to post here so I'll just lay out the meat of it:

- the commit hash is stored in an msbuild property, the command to get it is

  ```
  git --work-tree=$(GitVersionDir) --git-dir=$(GitVersionDir)\.git rev-parse --short HEAD
  ```

  where $(GitVersionDir) usually is set to $(MsbuildProjectDirectory) since we have most .vcxproj files in the source root.
- I also like the build date to be included so the property which eventually goes into the FileDescription entry of the StringFileinfo block is

  ```
  <FileDesc>$(GitVersion) $([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy'))</FileDesc>
  ```
- the actual file/product version, company name and other fields are fetched from elsewhere. Usually we have a common header file defining all VRC_XXX macros needed by the RC file template (see below), and a per-project header file containing e.g. #define VRC_FILEDESC "Project Foo", and those headers are merged using ReadLinesFromFile/WriteLinesToFile tasks. Anyway the idea is to end up with a header file like

  ```
  #define VRC_FILEVERSION 4,4,1,0
  #define VRC_PRODUCTVERSION 4.4.1.0
  #define VRC_COMPANYNAME MyCompany
  #define VRC_PRODUCTNAME VRC_COMPANYNAME Libraries
  #define VRC_FILEDESC Project Foo
  #define VRC_FILEDESCRIPTION VRC_FILEDESC VRC_FILEDESCGIT
  ```

  whos path is stored in a $(VersionMainInclude) property.
- all of this is fed to `rc.exe` to create the .res file. The full command is something like

  ```
  rc /d VRC_INCLUDE=$(VersionMainInclude)
     /d VRC_ORIGINALFILENAME=$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)
     /d VRC_FILETYPE=$(FileType)
     /d VRC_FILEDESCGIT=$(FileDesc)
     /d VRC_COPYRIGHT=VRC_COMPANYNAME \251 $([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(`yyyy`))
     /fo $(VersionResourceOut) $(MsBuildThisFileDirectory)version.rc
  ```
- Note the `MakeSameWriteTime` trick to set the modified time of the .res file the same as the output file, to assure the prebuild event doesn't trigger new builds each time it the .res file is generated. There might be better ways to do this, but this one works for me:

  ```
  <UsingTask TaskName="MakeSameWriteTime" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup>
      <SourceFile Required="true" ParameterType="System.String"/>
      <DestFile Required="true" ParameterType="System.String"/>
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
  System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime( DestFile, System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime( SourceFile ) );]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
  ```

This is the full .rc template used:

```
#include <winver.h>

#define stringize( x )        stringizei( x )
#define stringizei( x )       #x

#ifdef VRC_INCLUDE
  #include stringize( VRC_INCLUDE )
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32
  LANGUAGE 0x9,0x1
  #pragma code_page( 1252 )
#endif

1 VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION    VRC_FILEVERSION
 PRODUCTVERSION VRC_PRODUCTVERSION
 FILEFLAGSMASK  0x1L
 FILEFLAGS      VS_FF_DEBUG
 FILEOS         VOS__WINDOWS32
 FILETYPE       VRC_FILETYPE
BEGIN
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    BLOCK "040904E4"
    BEGIN
      VALUE "CompanyName",      stringize( VRC_COMPANYNAME )
      VALUE "FileDescription",  stringize( VRC_FILEDESCRIPTION )
      VALUE "FileVersion",      stringize( VRC_FILEVERSION )
      VALUE "LegalCopyright",   stringize( VRC_COPYRIGHT )
      VALUE "InternalName",     stringize( VRC_ORIGINALFILENAME )
      VALUE "OriginalFilename", stringize( VRC_ORIGINALFILENAME )
      VALUE "ProductName",      stringize( VRC_PRODUCTNAME )
      VALUE "ProductVersion",   stringize( VRC_PRODUCTVERSION )
    END
  END
  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
  END
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at my modification of MSBuild Community Tasks project at https://github.com/Bitrete/msbuildtasks. I've added a task called SemanticVersionGitDescribe. See the example of usage below.

```
<SemanticVersionGitDescribe LocalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)">
    <Output TaskParameter="SemanticVersion" PropertyName="Version"/>
    <Output TaskParameter="IsRelease" PropertyName="Release"/>
    <Output TaskParameter="AdditionalCommitsCount" PropertyName="AdditionalCommits"/>
    <Output TaskParameter="Hash" PropertyName="Hash"/>
</SemanticVersionGitDescribe>
```

And don't forget to put version string with hash only in `AssemblyInformalVersion` property. Because the `AssemblyVersion` property accepts only digits delimited by periods.

```
 <Target Name="UpdateAssemblyInfoVersion" DependsOnTargets="Prepare; GetGitVersion">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(EtcPath)\common\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs" DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs"/>
    <FileUpdate Files="$(EtcPath)\common\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs"
        Multiline="true"
        Singleline="false"
        Regex="(AssemblyVersion)\(&quot;([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)?&quot;\)"
        ReplacementText="$1(&quot;$(Version).$(AdditionalCommits)&quot;)" />
    <FileUpdate Files="$(EtcPath)\common\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs"
        Multiline="true"
        Singleline="false"
        Regex="(AssemblyFileVersion)\(&quot;([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)?&quot;\)"
        ReplacementText="$1(&quot;$(Version).$(AdditionalCommits)&quot;)" />
    <FileUpdate Condition=" $(Release) == False " 
        Files="$(EtcPath)\common\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs"
        Multiline="true"
        Singleline="false"
        Regex="(AssemblyInformationalVersion)\(&quot;([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)?&quot;\)"
        ReplacementText="$1(&quot;$(Version).$(AdditionalCommits)-g$(Hash)&quot;)" />
    <FileUpdate Condition=" $(Release) == True "
        Files="$(EtcPath)\common\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs"
        Multiline="true"
        Singleline="false"
        Regex="(AssemblyInformationalVersion)\(&quot;([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)?&quot;\)"
        ReplacementText="$1(&quot;$(Version)&quot;)" />
</Target>
```